# Nuxt 3: Firebase: Need to provide options, when not being deployed to hosting via source. (app/no-options)

Tags: javascript, firebase, vuejs3, yarnpkg, nuxt3

I have a `firebase.client.ts` file inside `plugins` folder:

```js
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getAuth } from 'firebase/auth';

const firebaseConfig = {
  /** Configuration here.. */
};


import { defineNuxtPlugin } from '#app';


export default defineNuxtPlugin((nuxtApp) => {
  // Initialize Firebase
  const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

  // Get Firebase Authentication instance
  const auth = getAuth(app);
  nuxtApp.$auth = auth;
});
```

And in `nuxt.config.ts` I have this line:

```js
plugins: [
    { src: '~/plugins/firebase.client.ts'},
  ],
```

However, when I try to build `yarn build` and `yarn preview`. I am getting this error:

[image]

What could be wrong in my code? Your responses are much appreciated. Thank you in advance :)

Comment: once the plugin is in the `plugins` folder they are automatically loaded in nuxt 3. you can remove this line `{ src: '~/plugins/firebase.client.ts'},`

You can read more on https://nuxt.com/docs/guide/directory-structure/plugins

Comment: @JoshuaOpata I did removing that line. However, the error still persist after building

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is a similar approach i use to handle my own Firebase plugin.
**NOTE: make sure the page using the firebase lib is has `ssr` disabled**

`~/plugins/firebase-plugin.ts`

```js
import { FirebaseOptions, initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import {
  FacebookAuthProvider,
  GoogleAuthProvider,
  PopupRedirectResolver,
  getAuth,
  signInWithEmailAndPassword,
  signInWithPopup,
} from "firebase/auth";

export default defineNuxtPlugin((nuxtApp) => {
  if (process.client) {
    const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig as FirebaseOptions);
    const auth = getAuth(app);

    const googleAuth = new GoogleAuthProvider();
    const facebookAuth = new FacebookAuthProvider();

    return {
      provide: {
        firebase: {
          app,
          auth,

          signInWithEmailAndPassword: async (email: string, password: string) =>
            signInWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password),

          signInWithGoogle: async (
            resolver?: PopupRedirectResolver | undefined
          ) => signInWithPopup(auth, googleAuth),

          signInWithFacebook: async (
            resolver?: PopupRedirectResolver | undefined
          ) => signInWithPopup(auth, facebookAuth),
          // ...
        },
      },
    };
  }
});
```

You can create a composable to expose it anywhere on a client-side rendered page

`~/composables/useFirebase.ts`

```js
export function useFirebase() {
  const { $firebase } = useNuxtApp();

  return {
    ...$firebase,
  };
}
```

Comment: Glad i was able to helped